# Real World Matrix Minimisation Problem

Tags: matrices

I have a problem  where I have three variables $x_1 , x_2, x_3$, where $ x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = k $.

I have a cost function where $a.x_1 + b.x_2 + c.x_3 = C $

I have a matrix where I can "switch" variables at cost of

\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & c_{1,2} & c_{1,3} \\
        -c_{1,2} & 1 & c_{2,3} \\
        -c_{1,3} & -c_{2,3} & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}

i.e. to move 1 unit of $x_1$ to $x_2$ costs $c_{1,2}$ . How do I minimize C, if I am given the values of $x_1 , x_2, x_3$ to start?

(Caveat is that this is a real world problem rather than a paper problem so it may not be expressed particularly concisely)

Comment: You have to explain a little bit more. How can be the negative entries interpreted in the real world ? What do the 1´s mean in this context?

Comment: Negative entries could be a negative cost therefore being paid to switch. Intuitively that makes sense if I pay to switch $x_1$ to $x_2$ I should be paid to go the other way.

Comment: Having said that this was a bit of a brain dump so potentially this should be $1/c_{m,n}$. Secondly the thinking of the 1's is that there is no switch/cost to stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

First some notation:

Let $x_1^0$, $x_2^0$ and $x_3^0$ be the starting values.

Let $z_{12}$ be the amount of capacity moved from 1 to 2 (could be negative!),
$z_{13}$ the amount of capacity moved from 1 to 3 and
$x_{23}$ the amount of capacity moved from 2 to 3.

Then $z_{12} + z_{13} + z_{23} = k - x_1^0 - x_2^0 - x_3^0$. (The right-hand side could be $0$ --- you did not specify whether the starting values satisfy the constraint $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 =k$.)

Then your problem is to
$$
\min c_{12}z_{12} + c_{13}z_{13} + c_{23}z_{23} \\
{\rm s.t.} z_{12} + z_{13} + z_{23} = k - x_1^0 - x_2^0 - x_3^0.
$$

This is a linear programming problem, for which plenty of software exists to solve it. Your problem is small enough that hand-calculations will give you a closed-form solution, but I do not have the time to develop that right now.

Comment: Apologies I should have been more concise $x_1^0 + x_2^0 + x_3^0 $ have to satisfy the constraint as do all other future combinations.

Any suggestions on best logic for solving this via "linear programming solution"? 

How would you see the computation time of this if we expand the problem to multiple variables rather than just a 3x3?

Comment: How many is "multiple"? Generally speaking, as long as the $x_i$ do not have to satisfy integrality requirements, computation time is not going to be an issue (fractions of a second), unless you are talking about massive numbers of units (hundreds of thousands, say).

Comment: It could be thousands but most likely not going to be more than that. What do you think would be an optimal solution? I'm not overly familiar with linear programming problems.

Comment: When one speaks of "linear programming" the process is the primary focus of interest. In your case the solution depends on the relative sizes of the switching costs, so it could be just about anything. The typical process is to build a model (equations that describe the system in general terms), which is what I tried to do in my answer. You can reuse this model every time you need to do another optimization (if the costs change, or the right-hand side value, for instance) without having to develop a new model.